# Удалённое подключение к MySQL

Tags: php, dle

Движок DLE.
Пытаюсь подключиться с web-хостинга BlazingFast к удалённой машине на Ubuntu с базой данных MySQL с помощью такого кода в файле движка dbconfig.php:

```
<?PHP

define ("DBHOST", "x-host-x");

define ("DBNAME", "x-name-x");

define ("DBUSER", "x-user-x");

define ("DBPASS", "x-pass-x");

define ("PREFIX", "dle");

define ("USERPREFIX", "dle");

define ("COLLATE", "utf8");

define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'x-key-x');

$db = new db;

?>
```

И выдаёт ошибку: Host 'x-host-x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: убедитесь, что mysql-сервер разрешает удаленные подключения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте файл `/etc/mysql/my.cnf/` и проверьте параметр `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`, это означает доступ со всех интерфейсов. Далее сделайте `telnet ip 3306` если есть доступ то значит получится подключится удаленно,и да создайте пользователя для удаленного подключения